# rails, Active Record Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end
```

and

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

how can I get all the articles without images

Comment: image_ids = Image.select(:article_id).map(&:article_id)  Article.where('id NOT IN (?)', image_ids)  I was hoping to have a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Article.where('id NOT IN (?)', Image.all.pluck(:article_id).uniq)
```